# How can I get the returned value of javascript using chromium web browser in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

How can I get the returned value of javascript using chromium web browser. I know how to put a value to a DOM element. But I do not know how to get the DOM element's value using cef sharp.
My sample code is like this.

```
//chromeBrowser = ChromiumWebBrowser object
String script = 
string.Format("document.getElementsByName('DOMElementName') 
[0].value;");
chromeBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script).ContinueWith(x =>
        {
           // I want to use the returned value of the script above
        });
```

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Of what type is the `chromeBrowser` variable ?

Comment: @PatrickHollweck It is the instance of chromium web browser initialized before.. "public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser= new ChromiumWebBrowser();" Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in the [official CefSharp FAQ](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#1-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-from-net) they have on their GitHub.

---

You need to wait for the `FrameLoadEnd` event to fire. Only after that can you evaluate a script. Then call `EvaluateScriptAsync` with the script string you want to execute on the frame, then you get back a Task which will contain the result of the operation.

```cs
browser.FrameLoadEnd += (sender, args) =>
{
  var task = args.frame.EvaluateScriptAsync(script, null);

  task.ContinueWith(t =>
  {
    if (!t.IsFaulted)
    {
      var response = t.Result;
      var result = = response.Success ? (response.Result ?? "null") : response.Message;
      // TODO: do something with the result
    }
  }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
};
```

Comment: Well thanks a lot for your answer. It was great. Is FrameLoadEnd similar to OnLoadingStateChanged event? Or they behave differently?

Comment: It is not exactly the same, but they can be used interchangeably, If you use `LoadingStateChanged` you need to check the `args.IsLoading` property. You can only execute scripts if it is `false`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it now.